# Providing ws security to soap webservices between mobile device and server

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to create webservice in soap with wssecurity and the webservice has to be handled in the mobile device. I have generated wsdl with many samples.

for your reference:

- http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/
- [ws-android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-android/)

Both the link works. But i need to add webservice security for this. I could not access this in android (using 1st link) It returns soap fault.

Can anyone give suggestion on doing this.

What i actually need is need to create the following header in webservice call from android.

```
<s:header>
 <wsse:security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">                              
      <wsse:usernametoken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">                              
           <wsse:username>TestUser</wsse:username>
           <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">TestPassword</wsse:password>
      </wsse:usernametoken>
 </wsse:security>
```

And I need to access this in my webservice. Please someone do help on doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568684/secure-web-service-requests  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853620/secure-web-services-rest-over-https-vs-soap-ws-security-which-is-better

Comment: Thanks. can you provide some sample code for doing ws security webservices.

Comment: I have answered to this question already please see here for the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730144/how-to-use-soap-based-web-service-android/6730579#6730579 .and for client side ui validation as well in a secured way.

Comment: Hi raghu, I have already done those things. Need to add headers and pass them to webservice which i created using the 1st link i have given.